# How to use paper.js as background in html

Tags: paperjs

I'm trying to use the "stars" example as a simple background in a html page, with html content on the page as well (I'm far from being into js. - simple html- and css-handling is ok).

What do I have to put into: 
- css (separate or inline)
- html head
- html body

I'm just looking into the .js use as a background. I managed to strike the mouse parameter as vector defining out of the stars code. This runs ok now just as is, but I either turn up in showing just the .js or the html content with missing the stars background. Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: What is the "stars" example that you are referring to ? Can you also post the code with which you are stuck so we can help you better ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have setup in my CSS

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Hope this helps